# Как ускорить чтение из файла в базу при большем объеме данных?

Tags: java, многопоточность, spring, csv

Пытаюсь решить следующую техническую задачу
У меня есть несколько csv-файлов, в каждом из которых от 4млн-11млн строк. Их мне нужно прочитать, сформировать объекты, обработать и записать в базу)

Сейчас я сделал mvp так, что читаю целиком файл за файлом, формирую ArrayList и последовательно прописываю все в базу

проблемы которые при этом подходe:

1. крайне долго
2. есть риск упасть с OutOfMemoryException

Как хочу решить:

1. Переходить к чтению след. файла только после как завершена работа с 
   предыдущим
2. Разбить ArrayList на куски по 10к (Как это сделать лучше?)
3. Создать какое-то кол-во потоков(модель Worker) и скормить им по мере 
   освобождения эти куски по 10к элементов для записи в базу. Соответственно 
   каждый поток будет иметь собственный конекшн из ThreadPool к базе.

Вопросы:
Есть ли очевидные косяки в решении?
Как разбить ArrayList на куски?
Сколько потоков безопасно создавать по умолчанию для такой задачи, 5-10?

При работе использую spring4, java8, oracle11g, was8.5.5.13

Comment: Зачем разбивать ArrayList? Не лучше ли использовать ограниченную очередь. Посмотрите в сторону реализаций Queue

Comment: А что мешает скопировать файл в доступное Ораклу место, а потом одним запросом импортировать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рецепта вам никто там прямо сразу не напишет - речь ведь идет о файн-тюнинге, а тут важна каждая деталь. Если грубо я бы померил скорость работы 3-х основных элементов конструкции:

1. Скорость чтения
2. Скорость обработки данных
3. Скорость вставки в БД (можно по одному, можно бэтчем/пакетом)

С большой долей вероятности, я ожидаю, что лвьиная доля времени уходит на чтение и запись (дисковые операции как правило всегда довольно длительные).

Отсюда и возникает сама идея: читать в одном потоке и писать в другом. Грубая схема будет такая:

- Сооружаем конструкцию в памяти, условно назовем буфер данных
- Запускаем поток(и) чтения, которые читают входные файлы и переводят их в буфер данных
- Запускаем поток записи, который проверяет буфер данных и все что попало в буфер данных пишет в БД, очищая буфер после записи

В общем и целом это паттерн [Producer-Consumer](https://dzone.com/articles/producer-consumer-pattern).

Реализаций данного паттерна много, начиная от тежеловесного JMS заканчивая более легковесными либами, можно и самому написать на основе [BlockingQueue](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/blockingqueue.html)